# I need to create a number range of 0001-9999 in xsl

Tags: xml, magento, xslt

Ok guys I am using magento 2. I have a module that lets me export product orders to another server. The server requires a specific "sequence_id". This sequence id isn't part of magento so I need to create it somehow and I'm lost.

Basically it has to be 4 digits. It can go from 0001 to 9999 then repeat. It needs to have preceding zeros.

I have a value "order increment id" from magento however that is about 7 characters long and doesn't reset at 9999.

Does anyone know how I can make this happen in XSL???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a small example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: Well the problem is that I have no current code to display.

Essentially I need my file name, and another field to be a number that increments going from 0001-9999

My text output is something like:

Value 1;Value 2;Value 3;0001 <--(sequence number)

Value 1,2,& 3 are generated from the Magento 2 system, basically a DB field or attribute. The sequence number has to be custom. So I have no idea how to generate it.

I do have an order number that magento supplies which could work, however it has too may characters like 000002, it also would not restart at 9999.

Comment: Do you know how to generate *any* value for each item in your input? If yes, you can (probably) use  `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(), '0000')"/>`. If you expect more that 9999 items, then use `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(position() mod 1000, '0000')"/>` to rolll back to 0 after 9999. -- This is assuming the purpose here is to tag your items with the sequential numbers - that's not clear from your question (as it's not clear what's the point of this, if duplicates are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can select `1 to 9999` and then use `format-number`:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="1 to 9999">
        <number>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '0000')"/>
        </number>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCTg

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt that your assumption is good: Magento -> PHP -> XSLT 1.0.

Comment: that did not work. 

Error: Please repair the XSL Template of this profile. There was a problem processing the XSL Template:
 Line 0 (Error Code: 1207): Invalid expression
 Line 0 (Error Code: 1): compilation error: element for-each
 Line 0 (Error Code: 1): xsl:for-each : could not compile select expression '1 to 9999'

Comment: That code is XSLT 2.0 and works with any XSLT 2.0 processor. If Magento exposes only an XSLT 1.0 processor then you can't use that approach.